# How to show javascript element only when I hover it on my div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering can anyone help me, basically I make `<div class="home"></div>` and then I found this code http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/tgEx6/7/, can anyone show me how to make the code I just found it only appear when I hover on `<div class="home"></div>` ? sorry about my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/tgEx6/2708/

You need to add display: none; to .stage and then to add this code for show/hide on hover

```
$('.home').hover(function(){
    $('.stage').show();   
}, function(){
    $('.stage').hide();
});
```

For adding fade effect you can change the code to this

```
$('.home').hover(function(){
    $('.stage').stop().fadeIn();   
}, function(){
    $('.stage').stop().fadeOut();
});
```